# Resultado inesperado em código de teste Lua

Tags: lua

Escrevi um pequeno código pra testar uma afirmação do livro através do qual estou estudando, Programming in Lua (3ª Edição).

A afirmação, que se encontra na página 10 do livro, traduzida é a seguinte: Testes condicionais (por exemplo, condições em estruturas de controle) consideram tanto o valor booleano `false` e `nil` como `false` e tudo mais como `true`.

```
function test (a)
    if a then print(type(a).." '"..tostring(a).."'".." corresponde a verdadeiro")
    else print(type(a).." '"..tostring(a).."'".." corresponde a falso") end
end

print("Teste 1: ")
test(true)

print("\nTeste 2: ")
test(0)

print("\nTeste 3: ")
test("")

print("\nTeste 4: ")
test("a")

print("\nTeste 5: ")
test(test)

print("\nTeste 6: ")
test(test("masuia"))

print("\nTeste 7: ")
test(false)

print("\nTeste 8: ")
test(nil)

print("\nTeste 9: ")
test(a) -- variável 'a' não foi inicializada, então corresponde a nil
```

Quando fui rodar o código, recebi o seguinte resultado no console:

```
Teste 1: 
boolean 'true' corresponde a verdadeiro

Teste 2: 
number '0' corresponde a verdadeiro

Teste 3: 
string '' corresponde a verdadeiro

Teste 4: 
string 'a' corresponde a verdadeiro

Teste 5: 
function 'function: 000000000026F2A0' corresponde a verdadeiro

Teste 6: 
string 'masuia' corresponde a verdadeiro
nil 'nil' corresponde a falso

Teste 7: 
boolean 'false' corresponde a falso

Teste 8: 
nil 'nil' corresponde a falso

Teste 9: 
nil 'nil' corresponde a falso
```

Por que ocorre o resultado do "Teste 6"? Segundo a afirmação do livro o teste não era pra ter resultado em falso, já que o parâmetro passado não foi o valor booleano false nem `nil`? Além disso, de onde saiu essa segunda linha do resultado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É totalmente consistente. Você percebeu que este passo 6 faz dois testes?

Primeiro ele executa `test("masuia")` e por isto a primeira linha é impressa. Até aí você deve estar achando tudo certo.

Depois ele executa novamente o teste chamando o resultado da função `test("masuia")`. Qual é este resultado, ou seja, qual é o valor retornado? Nenhum, ou seja, `nil`. Então a segunda chamada no fundo está executando `test(nil)`, e o resultado está certo. Olhando de outra forma aquela expressão poderia ser vista desta forma, só para você entender melhor:

```
temp = test("masuia") -- vai resultar em nil já que a função sem retorna tem valor nil
print(tmp) -- só para você ver o resultado intermediário.
test(tmp)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/IyMort). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vmwfchid-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Test.lua).

Não sei se você já aprendeu como funcionam expressões, de como funciona a chamada e retorno de funções.

Agora você deve estar se perguntando qual a diferença entre a chamada da função `test()` dentro da própria chamada da função `test()` e do exemplo 5 onde ele chama `test(test)`. O primeiro tem uma sintaxe de chamada, ou seja, a função `test` é executada naquele momento. Os parênteses dizem isto. No segundo caso você está apenas passando o valor contido no identificador `test`, que por acaso é uma função. Então ele funciona como uma variável e não faz a chamada da função. Podemos dizer que ele está "passando a função" como argumento, que é bem diferente de executar a função e passar seu resultado como argumento, como é o caso do exemplo 6.

Ele não passa todo o código, mas sim algo que indica onde está o código (não vou entrar em detalhes, é cedo para você aprender sobre isto). Este indicador é aquele número esquisito que aparece no teste 5, que é um endereço de memória.

Comment: Eu já tenho um certo entendimento de funções e expressões (assim como ponteiros) graças aos meus estudos de outras linguagens, mas não sabia que as funções Lua retornavam nil quando não fosse especificado retorno. Ótima resposta e muito bem explicada!

Comment: Muitas linguagens fazem isto, especialmente as dinâmicas, onde você precisa ter valor para tudo para dar mais flexibilidade.